# Magento topSearch not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, rwd-theme

I'm trying to display the (quick) search in the navigation menu.
Here is what I have so far:

**catalogsearch.xml**

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**top_nav.phtml**

```
<li><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?></li>
```

But the search bar isn't showing.

- I've refreshed the caches
- It isn't hidden by CSS, it isn't even showing in the inspector
- I'm working from the right template

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just change  `$this->getChildHtml('topSearch')` to  `$this->getBlockHtml('topSearch')`

## OR:

As you call this `searchbox`  as `child block` of in top_nav.phtml but you have call in  header child block in xml file.So it  not coming

So you need to change `reference parent block` of search from `header` to  top_nav.phtml file block.

Just like concept:

top_nav.phtml block name is topNav

guess that

```
<block type="...." name="topNav" template="..../top_nav.phtml ....
```

then

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**should be**

```
<reference name="topNav">
    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
</reference>
```